# How to Select Used Record in Foreign Key Table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys

I have two tables:

artist

```
A_id    A_name
1        name 1
2        name 2
3        name 3
```

song

```
s_id   AID   s_name
1       1    name
2       1    name
3       3    name
```

My problem is how can I select artist names from artist table only using song table. I need to get result like this:

```
A_id    A_nam
1       name 1
3       name 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `INNER JOIN` and `GROUP BY`. See the query and demo below:

```
SELECT 
      A.A_id,
      A.A_name 
FROM Artist A
INNER JOIN Song B
ON A.A_id=B.AID GROUP BY A_id,A_name
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d4b0a/2/0)**

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct A_id, A_Name
from artist
join song on (artist.A_id = song.AID)
```

or

```
select distinct A_id, A_Name
from artist
inner join song on (artist.A_id = song.AID)
```

Comment: Welcone to stackoverflow. While this code block might answer the question please try to add explanation in order to improve your answer. see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer